# To find file received time using find command in ssh server

Tags: linux

Below command gives syntax error

```
fname1=abc.txt

tim=`find /path/ -type f -name $fname1 -ls|awk '{print $8$9$10}'`

Syntax Error The source line is 1.
 The error context is
                 >>> {print <<<
 awk: 0602-502 The statement cannot be correctly parsed. The source line is 1.
```

Also tried to find file time of below command it also gives `printf` is not valid:

```
tim=`find /path/ -type f -name $fname1 -printf "%t"`
```

Comment: Can you please amend the post with what distribution & version of Linux you're using?

Comment: If we run the 'awk' command by line mode it is working. When we using backticks to run in the script that time fails :(..Please help me on this.

Comment: The syntax error is mentioned above. Is there anything wrong in above awk statement?

Comment: Which unix variant are you using? Which shell is the script running under? Try with `tim=$(find … | awk '{…}')` instead of the backticks, and with `#!/bin/ksh` instead of `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: Is that the full command you are typing or are you actually typing `ssh servername "... tim=..."` ? Doing the latter would explain why your awk variables, which look like shell variables to the shell, got expanded into empty strings.

Comment: Judging by the string `awk: 0602-502` there, it is likely that the remote ssh server is running AIX.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to put the time directly in the `tim` variable? You need to handle your backticks/shell escaping properly. The following works for me:

```
$ fname1=earch-0.8 ; dirpath=./
$ find $dirpath -type f -name $fname1 -printf "%t\n"
Mon Jan 16 00:52:43.0000000000 2006
$ find $dirpath  -type f -name $fname1 -ls | awk '{print $8$9$10}'
Jan162006
$ tim=$(find $dirpath -type f -name $fname1 -printf "%t")
$ echo "Time is '$tim'"
Time is 'Mon Jan 16 00:52:43.0000000000 2006'
```

Comment: The same awk command using along with backticks it is returning syntax error mentioned in above posts.

Comment: tim=`find /dirpath/ -type f -name $fname1 -ls|awk '{print $10}'`
tim=$(find /dirpath/ -type f -name $fname1 -printf "%t")           First statement gives syntax error second statement gives printf is not valid option when we run the script.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't try to [parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).
instead you should find a way to directly get the time.

if find's `-printf` option does not work for you, you probably have the "wrong" version of `find` installed on your system (on my Debian-box, `find` is part of the `findutils-4.4.2` package)

an alternative is using `stat`:

```
$ stat -c %x /path/to/file.txt
2013-12-09 15:40:29.000000000 +0100
$
```

together with `find`, you would use something like:

```
find $dirpath -type f -name $fname1 -exec stat -c %x \{\} \;
```

also note, that using writing the result into a variable with something like `tim=$(find ...)` will give you *multiple results* if you happen to have multiple files named `${fname}` in all subdirectories of `${dirpath}`

Answer (score 0):

use the command

> stat -c %y ${file_name}